# Gradle to run a command line process: execute() vs commandLine

Tags: gradle

In gradle, is there any reason not to use Groovy's .execute() function to run a command line process? I know the "gradle" way is to commandLine from Exec. But it feels like .execute() offers more flexibility such as being able to use in the doLast block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Gradle" way is to define tasks with a single responsibility, so task dependencies and results are clearly understandable and maintainable.  If you want more flexibility, just write a pure Groovy script.

Answer (score 6):

Gradle's `exec` is a lot different than Groovy's `.execute()`.  Gradle's `exec` will pipe the output to the stdout and wait for the command to complete before going to the next task.  Groovy's `.execute()` just returns a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).  That process will run in parallel in the background. You won't see the output unless you look for it, etc.

To make Groovy's `[].execute()` work like Gradle's `exec`, you'll have to define a method like this:

```groovy
void execute(String... args) {
  println "Executing $args...";
  def proc = args.execute();
  proc.in.eachLine {line -> println line}
  proc.err.eachLine {line -> println 'ERROR: ' + line}
  proc.waitFor()
}
```

And then in your task do something like this:

```groovy
task someTask() {
  doLast {
    execute("cmd", "/c", "echo Hello World!");
  }
}
```

And even in this case, your build won't fail if the task fails!

tl;dr Use Gradle's exec()

Comment: I believe `project.exec` is unavailable in a `Worker`, so thank you for posting this. FYI one can throw a `GradleTaskException` (or something along those lines in the worker) to fail the build on error. It just wraps throwable with task instance